# PHP/Magento: empty($object->property) returns true despite property is String

Tags: php, magento, object, properties

I set some value with Magento function setData:

```
$this->getChild('childBlockName')->setData('search_field_value', $this->__('field value'));
```

in parent .phtml file.

Then, in child .phtml file I try to get the value:

```
echo $this->search_field_value.'<br />';
$testvar = empty($this->search_field_value) ? 'empty value':'non empty value';
echo $testvar;
```

echoes:

```
'field value'
'empty value'
```

and:

```
$testvar = $this->search_field_value;
$testvar2 = empty($testvar) ? 'empty value':'non empty value';
echo $testvar2;
```

echoes:

```
'non empty value'
```

Why the object's property is being recognized as non-empty only after assigning it to a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is problem with php function

```
empty()
```

that function accept only parameter. If you have some function like:

```
function getValue(){
    return "hallo";
}
```

and then try to do something like:

```
echo empty(getValue());
```

you will get error, but if you try to do:

```
$val = getValue();
echo empty($val);
```

you will get right answer without error. That means the function empty() doesn't except function return value, only variable.

I hope that it helps.

explanation for magento:

yes, you are right, your code works fine, but in magento is a bit different then in your example, because magento actually uses magic functions and array:

when you set virtual variable in magento, it actually becomes part of array, not just virtual variable like in your example. If you take a look in magento function

```
public function setData($key, $value=null);
```

there is a line where you add your value in _data array:

```
$this->_data[$key] = $value;
```

so, when you do something like this:

```
$this->search_field_value
```

you are actually calling magic method __call and that function searches in _data array the entered value, in our case search_field_value. This is reason why magento returns empty.

Comment: I agree but I am trying to check `$this->search_field_value` which is an object's property, not method.

Comment: right, but it is not 'standard' object property because you have set it with method `setData()` and that property is virtual, not real.

Comment: It is not hard-coded, it's dynamic. I didn't realized that it makes a difference in this case! I will do some tests and get back to you with my results. Thanks :).

Comment: I've written a simple test and empty() that runs on the virtual/dynamic property set at runtime returns false. Please take a look at this code [link](http://codepad.org/8hBorVv5). I am not sure if Magent uses the same way of creating new properties though.

Comment: Thanks Marko for this educational answer. I've made a test with __get() [here](http://codepad.org/Q4QyDC3q) and it works as expected. __get() seems to be a magic method for properties and __call() is for methods. I haven't checked Magento's code though.